# R 3.4.1 on Windows 10; as.numeric still results in integer

Tags: r

I am learning about R, and came across this item. I was told that using the as."atomic class" should result in changing a class of an item. In that light, the code below should result in numeric, however, I am consistently getting integer. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong (this is purely for learning purposes, as I understand integer and numeric are very similar):

```
w <- 0:6
class(w)
# [1] "integer"
as.numeric(w)
# [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
class(w)
# [1] "integer"
```

Thank you

I also am not currently aware of how changing a character to numeric is relevant to my question. This is a different question in my limited knowledge. Please assist.

Comment: changing a character to numeric is not your question but the answer given is relevant. You haven't assign the result of `as.numeric`, so `w`is still of class `integer`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas is correct.  Use `w <- as.numeric(w)`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. So that is re-assigning. Makes perfect sense. Thanks everyone for the assistance, esp @Rui Barradas